# Passing custum hook inside callback

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I got a custom hook. I also got a component which expects a function.. The function needs to call my custom hook. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
<MyComponent onSuccess={(result) => useCustomHook("value", result)} />
```

My custom hook is something like:

```
export function useCustomHook(param1, param2)
{
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    dispatch(actionCreator.someAction(param1, param2));
    dispatch(actionCreator.setSomeValue(true));
}
```

I get an error saying:

> React Hook cannot be called inside a callback

I know of the rules saying I should call hooks only at the top level of a functional component, so how exactly can I achieve what I want here?

Comment: Maybe this will work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63712632/workaround-to-using-hooks-inside-callbacks/63712713#63712713

Answer (score 0):

I can't see what your custom hook is doing (more importantly, returning). But the implementation of the hook needs to look a bit like this:

```
function OtherComponent () {
  const callback = useCustomHook("value");

  return (
    <MyComponent onSuccess={(result) => callback(result)} />
  );
}
```

In your `useCustomHook`, you can return a function which you can call to do what you want to achieve.

If for example, you want to do a request each time the value changes, your custom hook could look like this:

```
function useCustomHook() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`http://my.api/${value}`);
  }, [value]);

  return setValue;
}
```

Now that the `setValue` is being returned from the `useCustomHook` function, it can be used in your component to change the `value` state inside the custom hook.

**edit**

You've added your custom hook, which will actually look really similar to the example from above:

```
export function useCustomHook(key) {
  const dispatch          = useDispatch();
  const [value, setValue] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(actionCreator.someAction(key, value));
    dispatch(actionCreator.setSomeValue(true));
  }, [key, value, dispatch]);

  return setValue;
}
```

The `useEffect` hook will only be called if one of the given "dependencies" changes. In the case above, this will only be the `value` which will be set when the return value is being called and the given value changes.

If `param1` never changes, it can be used as an argument of the custom hook, but if it does change, the hook will look a bit different:

```
export function useCustomHook() {
  const dispatch          = useDispatch();
  const [key, setKey]     = useState();
  const [value, setValue] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(actionCreator.someAction(key, value));
    dispatch(actionCreator.setSomeValue(true));
  }, [key, value, dispatch]);

  return (key, value) => {
    setKey(key);
    setValue(value);
  };
}
```

In your component you can use it like this:

```
function OtherComponent () {
  const callback = useCustomHook();

  return (
    <MyComponent onSuccess={(result) => callback('value', result)} />
  );
}
```

**2nd edit**

As discussed in the comments, for this situation, a custom hook isn't needed at all. You can just use a regular function and omit the `use` prefix:

```
function OtherComponent () {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const callback = (param1, param2) => {
    dispatch(actionCreator.someAction(param1, param2));
    dispatch(actionCreator.setSomeValue(true));
  };

  return (
    <MyComponent onSuccess={(result) => callback('value', result)} />
  );
}
```

If you still want to make a custom hook and call the dispatch every time the function gets called, the custom hook can be as simple as:

```
export function useCustomHook() {
  const dispatch          = useDispatch();

  return (key, value) => {
    dispatch(actionCreator.someAction(key, value));
    dispatch(actionCreator.setSomeValue(true));
  };
}
```

Comment: I have edited with the custom hook implementation which doesn't return anything. Could you base the answer according to my addition?

Comment: I don't understand why I need to add useState? I'm planning just to call the custom hook with its parameters like a regular function every time I need it

Comment: You don't really need a hook actually. In this case, it is perfectly fine to use a function inside your function component which calls the dispatch function.

Comment: Updated the answer, with and without a custom hook.

Comment: @Christiaan sometimes you need the same in different components, and you would need to dispatch login repeated all over.

Comment: @user3808307 that is true. However, a single dispatch can still be a one-liner.

Comment: @Christiaan unless you have a bunch of conditions under which the dispatch is made