# Workaround to using hooks inside callbacks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have in the redux store, some elements which I am either waiting for response form an API or have already received the response.

I had the idea of creating a hook as to not repeat the logic in every component in which I need to do this.

But of course I am getting an error of not being able to use hooks inside callbacks

The use case is like this: Suppose I receive alphabet letters from an API1. For each letter I have received from the API1, I have to make a call to API2 to get more details on that letter, so I want to check first if I have already made the request to API2 for this particular letter, and if not, make it.

To simplify, I will omit the case where the call was made to API2 but the response has not yet arrived.

This is my hook

```
useDetails = (letter) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const { lettersDetails } = useSelector(state => ({
    lettersDetails: state.api2.lettersDetails
  }));

  const [details, setDetails] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    if (letter) {      
      // See of I already have details for this letter 
      const letterDetails = _.find(lettersDetails, function(o) { return o.letter === letter; });
      if (!letterDetails) {
        dispatch(getLetterDetailsAction(letter))        
      } else {
        setDetails(`The place of ${letterDetails.letter} in the alphabet is ${letterDetails.position}`)
      }
    }
  }, [lettersDetails]);

  return details;
}
```

In my component now, I am receiving letters from another api, api1, and creating a array with them

What I would like to do is for each letter I receive use the hook as follows, but I can't. What alternative is there?

```
export default () => {      
  const { letters } = useSelector(state => ({
    letters: state.api1.letters // this is an array 
  }));
  const [mappedLetters, setMappedLetters] = useState([])


  useEffect(() => {

    setMappedLetters(letters.map(letter => { 
      return {
        letter,
        description: useDetails(letter) // here i want the return value from the hook
      }
    }))    
}, [letters])
```

The thing is this logic needs to be repeated across several components

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return an accessor to the value instead of the value itself from your custom hook:

```js
// hook
function useDetails() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const [details, setDetails] = useState('')
  const { lettersDetails } = useSelector( ... )

  return useCallback((letter) => {
    // have access to letter & lettersDetails
    const letterDetails = // ...
    if (!letterDetails)
      dispatch( ... )
    else
      setDetails(letterDetails)
    return details
  }, [lettersDetails])
}

// component
export default () => {
  // ...
  const getLetter = useDetails()
  useEffect(() => {
     const description = getLetter(letter)
     // ...
  }, [letters])
}
```

Comment: You might want to look into having this whole logic "inside" a redux selector too (with an async thunk dispatching the getLetterDetailsAction). This might be the most idiosyncratic way of doing it (if you have a recent enough version of redux on the project).

Comment: the redux toolkit lib by the authors of redux: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk or if you don't want to add another package, just the redux doc: https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions